# GUI frontend for R script

Tags: windows, r, user-interface

We have a set of R scripts, which process some data and produce some results. We want to make these scripts available to basic users, which are not used to commandline of R - we want to **provide them some nice GUI, which would allow to:**

- import/export data from MS Excel/Access easily (also supporting Copy/Paste if possible)
- allow user to change settings/parameters of the process
- should be running in MS Windows.

**Is there any simple, scripting environment which would allow to develop such nice GUI for our R scripts as fast as possible?** Need not necessarily be in R language.

Comment: Probably does a lot more than what you need/want, but [R Commander](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/) has all these features.

Comment: @Chase, thanks, this is a nice thing, but does this really allow me to easily create GUI frontend for our custom scripts? At the first sight, it looks like a frontend for most often used R functionality, not a framework for making my own frontends.

Comment: good question, I honestly have only used R Commander once. I do remember from the UseR! Conference a few years ago that lots of people had made custom GUI interfaces and most of them had the RCMDR logo in the corner...this is why I posted as a comment and not an answer :)

Comment: I would have thought you'd have just started with tcltk by now for a project like this. Just searching for CRAN packages with "tk" in the name reveals that some people have built gui front ends for their packages.

Comment: tcltk or gwidgets (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/index.html)

Comment: Deducer as well. http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Development

Comment: Thank you guys! If I understood it well, all these things (gwidgets, tcltk, deducer) are available as R packages, so can be scripted from R, am I correct? So I don't need to learn a new language, right?

Comment: I have finally used gwidgets with the RGtk2 toolkit. It is not ideal (e.g. I don't know how to customize the looks), but it is very easy to learn and use and very fast to develop in it.

Answer (score 4):

There is the RExcel tool that incorporates R as an Excel plugin so the main interface is Excel with R doing the computations in the background.  You could set up a sheet so that the user enters their data, then highlights a box and then chooses a menu item or clicks a button and the results are placed in another cell (or set of cells).  Note however, that RExcel and the comunication program it user are not free.

Another option is to create your own gui function in R, then have that gui run automatically when you start R (see ?STARTUP) and set this up on the users machine.  I have done this for clients before that did not know anything about R, they just double clicked on the icon on the desktop (windows), minimized the main R window when it opened, interacted with the gui that I had programmed to run (I used tcltk, but there are others) and saw the output provided.

You can get data copied from Excel by having the user select the data and click on copy, then in your program run `newdata <- read.delim('clipboard')` and the data will be in the data frame called 'newdata', you can use `write.table(outdata, file='clipboard', delim='\t')` to put the data from data frame 'outdata' onto the clipboard and the user can then paste it into Excel (or other programs).

There is also the Rcmdr package which provides a general GUI for R (basic tools) but also has a mechanism where you can create your own menus and dialog boxes for use with the GUI.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I'll have look at it and maybe come back with a question. THanks.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say it had to be a desktop program. So `Jeroen Ooms'` hilarious [openCPU](http://public.opencpu.org/pages/) project might be worth a look. He basically calls it statistical computing in the cloud. The guys has been really active recently (now that I checked the website again, I realized it's new again).

Also, his earlier work [stockplot](http://rweb.stat.ucla.edu/stockplot/) or [ggplot demo](http://labs.dataspora.com/ggplot2/) is very interesting. Especially a brief look at `stockplot` gives you an impression quickly of his approach.

Afaik, RApache is used and the nice frontend GUI is created with `EXTJS` .
I think the documentation can explain the approach much better than I do.

I think R on a webserver – particularly for intranet use is a good solution (depending on the size of your company), because:

- it's platform independent, clients can use their favorite browsers
- local development and deployment of script and even whole R pakacges is easy
- Reporting / Publishing is big strength of R and can be facilitated using a web based architecture (see packages like `knitr` or `sweave`

Comment: Thank you ran2, this is an interesting answer. I'll have a look at it and may be come back with a question.

Answer (score 2):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22723673/684229) I just come around R shiny:

http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/