# How to place gwindow inside main R window

Tags: r, gwidgets

I'm using `gwindow()` function to open new window in gwidgets in R. But it opens new window in windows. I want it to open a subwindow **within** main R window. How can I force that? There is an option `parent` to `gwindow()` function, but I would need a handle to main R window...

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with gWidgets.  It sounds like you would need to hack the code for the RGui itself.

Comment: @Dason and what about other GUI tools for R, like tcltk, deducer etc. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144122/gui-frontend-for-r-script)

Comment: I don't see how that is related.  Maybe this is an indication that you need to provide more details for what it is you actually want to do...

Comment: @Dason, all I want to do is described in the question - open the window within R. Problem is that we don't understand each other, could you please express your answer for less technically skilled person? I got lost with your "you would need to hack the code for the RGui itself" in your 1st comment. And what do you mean by "I don't see how that is related"? Could you please be more specific? Thanks!

Comment: Like I said before gWidgets will let you open a new window.  But if you want something to show up "as a window inside of R" (which I take to mean to show up as a new window contained within RGui so that RGui is the ) then you can't do that using gWidgets - plain and simple.  I don't think any other gui toolkit will get you around that problem.  Is there a particular reason you don't want a new window to pop up?  You should also just clarify if you're using RGui within Windows...

Comment: thanks @Dason, now it's much more clear! I don't want new window, because it is incoherent with normal behaviour of sources and graph windows... user is not used to it. And when you switch to console, you don't see the gwidget window. And yes, there is a Windows window named RGui, so I guess I use RGui :-)

Comment: Then I believe the answer is that you can't do that.  (By the way you should check out [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/)... RGui is very lacking in my opinion.

Comment: @Dason you answered my question, please create a normal answer, I will upvote and accept.