# R shiny multiple selection with a scroll bar

Tags: r, shiny

I am using R shiny to develop a web application. Now I want to do multiple selection(not just one) from multiple choices. I tried checkboxGroupInput, but it will give a long list. What function can create things like this? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `selectInput` with the argument `multiple = TRUE`, as can be seen in [the documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/selectInput).

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your answer. I tried that before, seams it only allow you to select one variable from multiple choices, but cannot do multiple selection.

Comment: You can select several choices with `ctrl`+click

Comment: We just released Shiny 0.9, which changes the default behavior of `selectInput()` to a fancy javascript-based selector (including support for multiple item selection without ctrl+click). There is a screenshot in our [blog post](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/03/27/shiny-website-and-0-9/).